# Is there a way in C++ to create 'super private' variables?

Tags: c++, oop

I had an idea for a feature for C++, and I was wondering if it was possible to create.

Let's say I want a private variable in 'MyClass' to be accessible only by two functions, the public getter and setter. That is, if another public or private function of MyClass tries to get or change the value of my super-private variable, I will get a compile error. However, the getter and setter behave normally.

Any ideas?

Edit 1: A use case is having the getter/setter perform error checking or other form of logic. I wouldn't want even the class itself touching the variable directly.

Edit 2:
Something like this then:

```
template <class T>
class State{
private:
    T state;

public:
    State()
    {
        state = 0;
    }

    T getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    void setState(T state)
    {
        this->state = state;
    }
};
```

And then any class can inherit it and access 'state' only through the getter/setter. Of course, the class is useless without modifying the getter and setter according to your desired logic.

Comment: Can you provide a usecase?

Comment: So you're probably doing the design the wrong way :  if the field has nothing more to do than being accessed and stored in the class, it might as well be in another class.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible, although it would be really nice when you have logic associated with your getters/setters.  I've always just tried to remember to use the getters/setters since most times you will be the class owner.

Comment: I feel compelled to create a language just to include the awesome concept of "Super Privacy." It will also feature "Super Publicity."  Now I just need to invent the "Spidy Sense" programming paradigm.

Comment: @mikerobi make sure you also include an "Any Publicity Is Good Publicity" feature.

Comment: Getters/Setters are meant to be used from outside. The class itself is supposed to access the fields directly.

Comment: [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming))?

Answer (score 64):

The granularity of accessibility in C++ is the class.

So if you need to make a variable accessible to only two methods you need to move the variable and the two methods into a separate class, dedicated to maintaining privacy..

Comment: I think, the term *"accessibility"* should be used here, rather than *"visibility"*, because the term *visibility* has different meaning in C++.

Comment: @Nawaz Thank you. So many languages and so many different names for the same things!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't think other languages use the term *visibility* to mean *accessibility*; at least not those in which you can *hide* a name.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In that case, in Delphi, there is no concept of *name hiding*, right?

Comment: @Nawaz What do you mean by hiding?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: By that I mean this : http://ideone.com/FqfXg ... and to fix this, you've to unhide as shown here : http://ideone.com/dRGTL

Comment: @nawaz Yes you can hide in the same way in Delphi. I'm talking about private/public which are called visibility specifiers in delphi but are access specifiers in c++?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If Delphi can hide name, then what term uses it to *describe* it?

Answer (score 31):

You could wrap the variable in a class and make it private there and a `const T&` getter. Than you declare the get and set member functions of the containing class as friends to that wrapper. Now you keep the wrapper class as a member in your original class. That should achieve what you want albeit it looks hard to maintain and not very useful.

So here is some dummy implementation that shows how this would work (Note that the whole `new VeryPrivateWrapper` business is just a wacky way around declarations, a `unique_ptr` would be more helpful):

```
class VeryPrivateWrapper;

class Original {
  VeryPrivateWrapper* m_wrapper;

public:
  Original();
  // imagine that I remembered the rule of three here
  void set(int);
  void other();
};

// make this a template for more fun
class VeryPrivateWrapper {
  int m;
public:
  const int& get() const { return m; } 
  // !!!
  // the important bit 
  // !!!
  friend void Original::set(int);
};

Original::Original() : m_wrapper(new VeryPrivateWrapper) {}

void Original::set(int i) {
    m_wrapper->m = i;
}

void Original::other() {
  // this borks as we would like
  // m_wrapper->m = 23;
}

int main()
{
  Original o;
  o.set(3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you could just make MyClass inherit from the wrapper (possibly not publicly), so you won't need that friendship setting or making the wrapper a member.

Comment: @eran How would other member functions then go about accessing the member? I thought that was a requirement. Because if the mutating getter of the base class is accessible to the outside it is accessible to the base as well, right?

Comment: I'm assuming the getter and the setter can be part of `VeryPrivateWrapper`, so all member functions of `Original` can use them to get or set the super-private. If the getter and setter must be part of `Original`, then I guess your idea of using friendship is the only option.

Comment: @eran I thought the important part was that all functions default to read-only access and only the setter function should be able to have write access.

Comment: Does C++0x support anonymous classes? That might be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is what you asked for.  Is it desirable?  Some people will think this is an abomination.

If you decided to use it, you'll probably want to pull out the public Get and Set from the macro and write those manually.

```
#define SUPER_PRIVATE(c,t,m) \
template <typename C, typename T> \
class SuperPrivate##m { \
    friend T& C::Get##m(); \
    friend void C::Set##m(const T&); \
    T value; \
}; \
public: \
    t& Get##m() { return m.value; } \
    void Set##m(const t& value) { m.value = value; } \
private: \
    SuperPrivate##m<c,t> m; 

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass()
    {
        SetX(42);
        SetY(58);
    }
    int DosomethingWithX() { return GetX() * 2; }
//  int DosomethingWithX2() { return X.value * 2; } // error
//  int DosomethingWithX3() { return X; } // error

    SUPER_PRIVATE(SomeClass, int, X);
    SUPER_PRIVATE(SomeClass, int, Y);
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass someObject;
    int x1 = someObject.GetX();
    int y1 = someObject.GetY();
    someObject.SetY(89);
    int y2 = someObject.GetY();
    int x2 = someObject.DosomethingWithX();

}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to call those macros an usability improvement compared to my attempt.

Answer (score 5):

I would put a very ugly name to the variable, and a nice one to the getter/setter:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int _hey_do_not_use_me_im_super_private_whatever;
public:
    int get_whatever() const
    {
        //extra logic
        return _hey_do_not_use_me_im_super_private_whatever;
    }
    void set_whatever(int we)
    {
        //extra logic
        _hey_do_not_use_me_im_super_private_whatever = we;
    }
};
```

A comment expaining what super-private means will be most welcome by the people that inherits your code.

Comment: Well, a macro like `#define SUPERPRIVATE(x) superprivate_##x` can be used, but personally I find it rather superfluous.

Comment: I agree such a macro would not be necessary but I was referring to my own answer which has a rather more involved macro.  I guess it comes down to the difference between enabling the compiler to catch silly things versus trusting people not to do silly things.  Typing out _hey_do_not_use_me_im_super_private_whatever every time would be silly so your answer is probably sufficient.  On the other hand, the OP did ask for a solution that would result in a compiler error but I still think your answer deserves a +1.