# Have a method being only usable by a unique type of class

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I am currently looking for a proper way to restrain the usage of a method by a specific type of class. To be more clear, here is the situation:

I have a class dedicated to networking in a server (let's call it `ClientSession`). A client, once connected to the server, has 30 seconds to authenticate or the server will close the connection.

The authentication is handled by another class on the server (let's call it `Authenticator`), which will be supposed to 'warn' `ClientSession` that the client authenticated successfully and the 30 sec timer can be cancelled.

The problem is, that would require `Authenticator` to call a public method of `ClientSession`. But I don't want that method to be able to be called by anyone.

To summarize, I want `Authenticator` to be the only class able to call the `ClientSession::clientAuthSuccessful()` method.

I've looked into two things:

- Friend methods, but I don't want `Authenticator` to be able to access all private methods and properties or `ClientSession` through the friend method.
- Visitor design pattern, but it doesn't seem to do exactly what I want (unless I misunderstood its usage).

Is there another way to have such specific restrictions? Or a clean alternative?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582664/is-there-a-way-in-c-to-create-super-private-variables/7582721#7582721 might be what you are looking for. But I'd just go with good old documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler way.  Just pass some special-purpose piece of code from the `ClientSession` to the `Authenticator`.  You can achieve this using a function pointer, function object or lambda function.

```
class ClientSession
{
public:
    void startSession ( Authenticator& authenticator )
    {
        // pass function pointer to method to call when
        // the timeout for authentication has elapsed.
        authenticator.start(this, &ClientSession::warnThat30SecsHasPassed);

        // alternative syntax, using new lambda function syntax,
        // which will end up reducing coupling between the two classes.
        authenticator.start([this](){ warnThat30SecsHasPassed() });
    }
private:
    void warnThat30SecsHasPassed () { ... }
};

class Authenticator
{
public:
    // classic way.
    void start ( ClientSession * session, void(ClientSession::*callback)() );

    // using new syntax.
    void start ( std::function<void()> callback );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it seems like a good way to 'forcibly' bypass the privacy of the method. I never looked into lambda functions before, took me some time to understand (and I'm not sure I still got the whole idea, it only seems to avoid entering a new scope when using function pointers) but it does the trick. Not sure if it is the cleanest thing, but I might use it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jukurrpa: given C++'s lack of lambda functions until C++11, this is not (yet) an idiomatic way to write C++, but is a common way of "dealing" with this problem in many languages, including C#.  As support for lambda functions becomes more widespread, I suspect this technique will become more commonplace.

Comment: I read your answer again now that I have a better understanding of lambda expressions, and it seems to me that it is the best and simplest solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Define an interface, `AuthenticatorListener`, with the `clientAuthSuccessful()` method defined in it (as pure virtual).

Make `ClientSession` inherit from the `AuthenticatorListener` privately and implement the method (privately).

Then have the `ClientSession` instance pass itself to the `Authenticator`.

Now no other class can access the method. And `Authenticator` is not coupled to the `ClientSession`, only to a suitably segregated interface.

Comment: It seems to do the job and it is pretty clean. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, in fact there's something I did not think about... Any class which has a pointer to `ClientSession` would just have to cast it to `AuthenticatorListener` to access the private method. So it somewhat is more secure but still not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There's no clean way of doing this, no. You either use friend classes, or public methods.

No clean way doesn't mean not possible. I would never write code like this, and neither should you, but the following does follow the requirements:

```
class Lock
{
    friend class B;
private:
    Lock() {};
};


class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    void foo(Lock x){}
};

class B
{
    void foo()
    {
        Lock l;
        A a;
        a.foo(l);
    }
};
```

Since `class B` is the only class that can create `Lock` instances, and `A::foo` requires a `Lock` instance as a parameter, it can only be called by `B`.

**Don't do this though. I'd suggest adding comments and documentation to the headers.**

Comment: That looks pretty ugly indeed. Isn't this somewhat of a 'common' problem? It's not the first time I need to do this kind of restriction, but I've never find anything about it... It makes me wonder if requiring this just means the design I made isn't 'clean' and if there is a completely different way to do things.

Comment: I guess that would be called `pass-key` idiom.

Comment: @Jukurrpa there probably is a more clean design, but probably requiring a lot more refactoring. Also, just because a problem is often encountered, doesn't mean it has a solution. C++ doesn't have reflection, there are no friends in Java, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a proxy class that `ClientSession` friends and that friends `Authenticator`.

Comment: Well, it somewhat will be the same problem, the proxy class will have access to all of `ClientSession`s members... And even though I 'trust' the proxy, I may have to do this kind of restriction for other methods, which means a proxy class for each method, which will be kinda messy :)

Comment: No, it won't. Friendship is not transitive: my friends friends are not my friends. (Say that ten times fast.) As to it being clumsy if there are a large number of combinations, no arguing with that.

Comment: @smparkes: what OP said has nothing to do with transitivity.  If `ClientSession` friends `Authenticator`, then `Authenticator` has access to *all* of `ClientSession`'s private members, not just a single method.

Comment: @AndréCaron: I know. My comment about transitivity was with respect to his comment that a proxy has the same problem which is not the case because of friendship's lack of transitivity.

Comment: I think we're all saying the same thing from different points of view.  Jukurrpa means the the proxy class definition will have full access to `ClientSession` internals (`ClientSession` is still given full access to *some* other class), and you mean the proxy class's clients will have only access to the access that the proxy class grants.

Comment: Good point. I think of the proxy as being an extension of `ClientSession`, under control of `ClientSession` (could even be nested within `ClientSession`) so I think of it as being safe but that's a judgement call.

Comment: @smparkes: I agree.  Anyways, for a `friend` declaration to be useful, you have to write both classes together anyways (to grant friend access on one side and use the access on the other).  I tend to prefer a solution that doesn't forcibly bind the two classes if I can find one, though.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with a problem, one often gets an idea about how to solve it, and spend our efforts on how to implement that solution. Sometimes, the better to revisit the problem and think about other solutions.

For example, rather than having the `Authenticator` try to notify a `ClientSession` that was passed into it (or better yet, by invoking some sort of *callback* passed into it), what about letting the `ClientSession` (or some other object / thread) invoke a method like `Authenticator::waitForAuthentication(int timeout)`?

---

Edit: I thought I'd elaborate on the *callback* notion. The point is that `Authenticator` doesn't need knowledge of the `ClientSession` class to do it's job; it just needs to know to invoke some function or other callable.

So, you write your `Authenticator` to have a method that accepts some `std::function` object of the right signature, and have `ClientSession` (or whatever) create a suitable thing to pass in. It could be a specialized function object similar to what Luchian Grigore suggests. Maybe it is a slightly more generic object, or maybe one that is initialized with references to the private parts of your `ClientSession` object. Or it's a lambda, if you can use C++11.

That said, I suspect having a `waitForAuthentication` method (or something else entirely) may very well be what you *really* want for your application.

Comment: Well, I have tried to think about other ways to pass the message, but the thing is the `ClientSession` has to handle other things and specifically waiting for a response isn't possible, or checking if the authentication was successful from time to time doesn't seem clean to me.

Comment: It's common to set up message queues for your objects, so passing the message can be done just by dropping it into the right queue. If you just make sure only the `ClientSession` and `Authenticator` get references to that queue, I think that suits your needs.